# Number of child processes spawned issue?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def info(title):
    print("~"*50)
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def foo():
    info("foo()")
    print("bar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
        p.start()
        p.join()
        time.sleep(1)
```

It works like a charm for what I want to do. As I observe the scripts being excecuted, the PID's are going up really high.

Example output:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo()
module name: __main__
parent process: 1104
process id: 4805
bar
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo()
module name: __main__
parent process: 1104
process id: 4806
bar
```

Yet, the PID's seen via `top` do not change:

```
 1104 x3         20   0 60060 18252  8560 S  0.7  1.9  0:20.55 │           └─ python3 clockMatrix7219.py
 1109 x3         20   0 60060 18252  8560 S  0.0  1.9  0:00.00 │              ├─ python3 clockMatrix7219.py
 1108 x3         20   0 60060 18252  8560 S  0.0  1.9  0:00.00 │              ├─ python3 clockMatrix7219.py
 1107 x3         20   0 60060 18252  8560 S  0.0  1.9  0:00.00 │              ├─ python3 clockMatrix7219.py
 1106 x3         20   0 60060 18252  8560 S  0.0  1.9  0:00.00 │              └─ python3 clockMatrix7219.py
```

`clockMatrix7219.py` is the name of the script.

My question is: Can this be problematic in the future? Will there be a limit? Because the script is intended to run at all times. Also the processes each run only for a fraction of a second and are finished after.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got zero response but I figured out how to avoid spaning new processes every loop.

I've simply put the `while loop` inside the function.

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def info(title):
    print("~"*50)
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def foo():
    while True:
        info("foo()")
        print("bar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    time.sleep(1)
```